# Extract data from one ArrayList in one java file and show it in different java file in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one java file named Employee.java.i have to read a CSV file where the employee details are stored i.e;

```
(Employee_ID, Employee_Name, Employee_Designation, Employee_Mobile, Employee_Year_Of_Joining).
```

i have to convert it into an ArrayList.

Another file Project.java where i have to read another CSV file where the project details are stored i.e;

```
(Project_ID, Project_Name, Project_Description, Project_Start_Date, Project_End_Date, Employee_ID).
```

i have to convert this also into an ArrayList.

Now i have to send the Employee_ID and extract the Employee_Name and Employee_Designation and the output is-

### OutPut

Project_Name
Project_Description
Employee_Name
Employee_Designation

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > aList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String> >(); 

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Office/Practice/collection/Emp.CSV"));
     String data=null;
     while((data=br.readLine())!=null){
      String[] token = data.split(",");
      ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int i=0;i<token.length;i++) { 
       
      a.add(token[i]);
      }
      aList.add(a);

Comment: Post additional detail as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are learning Java, do writing all the code for you would be a disservice. And Stack Overflow is not intended to be a “write my code for me” service.

So here is a narrative to walk you through the steps to take in writing your code. Tip: Learn to use these four steps to programming: write requirements as you did in the Question, write a plain language description to walk through the logic, as I did here, then write pseudo-code without worrying about the exact syntax of any particular programming language so you can work out the nuances and details, and finally write your code.

## Write classes (or not)

If you will be doing further work with this data, write a class for each type, an `Employee` class and a `Project` class. Then read each input file, parsing each row to instantiate an object of the class you just wrote.

If not doing further work, you could skip writing the classes. In my description of looping below, substitute a row of input data for where I say Employee or Project object.

Tip: Use any of the several libraries for reading and parsing the CSV files. For example, *Apache Commons CSV*.

## Nested loop

How would you do this if you were a clerk rather than a programmer, with two written lists and a typewriter in front of you? The same logic applies here in programming.

Write a loop, going through the Project list.

For each Project element, get the project’s employee ID number.

Write a second loop, going through the Employee list. Extract from each Employee object the employee ID number. Compare this employee ID number to the employee ID number we have in hand for the project. If they match, write your result. And if they match, you can break out of this inner loop as there is no reason to continue examining further employee objects. If you exhaust the employee list without a match, you have an error condition to resolve however you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for this comment sir could you please just write the function where i will send  project’s employee ID number and the function where it will receive.

Comment: i had already the csv file just need to pass the  project’s employee ID number to Employee.java where it will return me the required data as per match.but it is giving me error again and again.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I have a code  to help you. it reads a excel and save an arraylist. you should only duplicate to code to read the second csv

[read csv java](https://github.com/wilson1234567891962/Excel-Java-Read.git)

the code is the next, maybe you should add the neccesary library to run its. You find the library that i used at pom

```
package com.examen.excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> dta = new ArrayList<>();
            try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("C:\\Users\\wilso\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Excel\\src\\resources/Employment.xlsx"))) {
                Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
                StringBuilder result;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    result = new StringBuilder();
                    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                result.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                result.append(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                break;
                        }
                        result.append(":");
                    }
                    dta.add(result.toString());
                }
                System.out.println("Resultado");
                System.out.println(dta);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The second option is the next

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.generic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\wilso\\Desktop/PRUEBA.csv")));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(line);
            }
            //Read the second file and do matching
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not even about CSV files but about parsing xlsx files with the apache poi library. Also, a link is not an answer.

Comment: the link has the necessary code to read a excel, as consequence i consider that it permits to respond the question, also  you can read xlsx or csv. Just one look the code

Comment: Also, I think parsing csv files without a library is easier that using this library...

Comment: I don't think so, because the link is a code that implements to read an excel. if you show me as read a excel without library,  i would like to look its

Comment: The question is about reading a CSV file. It is way easier to read a csv file than a xlsx file. I think it is easier to read a csv file than it is to read an xlsx file with your code.

Comment: I think to read CSV, no Apache POI is required. In java it can be done using it's own BufferReader and FileReader.
BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToCsv));

Comment: Also, I think reading the csv file isn't even the big problem(see the comments to the question).

Comment: @dan1st and @ Fahim Ahmed had the reason, sorry i didn't know that it is possible to read a csv with buffer. I often use library for its

Comment: CSV is a very easy file type.